# Add font awesome to admin bar in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I am adding icons with javascript in my admin bar but the icon are displayed with "squares", so I tried adding the style with the icon like this :

```
$('#wp-admin-bar-root-default').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" id="commentator-font-awesome-css"  href=".../css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" /><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step by Step example using FontAwesome:**

Including color and custom post types

Step by Step example using FontAwesome:

Including color and custom post types

1 Pick an icon

Goto: http://fontawesome.io/icons/
Pick an icon, I have chosen "fa-flask" for this example.

2 Get the SVG

Goto: https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/tree/master/black/svg
Find the icon, it will be the name without the fa prefix - in my case, that is "flask.svg".
Click the icon, then click "Raw" in Github
Bring the SVG into Wordpress

Inside your functions.php, where you register your custom post type, add the following snippet:

```
add_action('init', 'my_init');
function my_init() {
    register_post_type('labs', [
        'label' => 'Labs',
        // .. ect
        'menu_icon' => 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' . base64_encode('<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="black" d="M1591 1448q56 89 21.5 152.5t-140.5 63.5h-1152q-106 0-140.5-63.5t21.5-152.5l503-793v-399h-64q-26 0-45-19t-19-45 19-45 45-19h512q26 0 45 19t19 45-19 45-45 19h-64v399zm-779-725l-272 429h712l-272-429-20-31v-436h-128v436z"/></svg>')
     ]);
}
```

**Important notes:**

The contents of base64_encode is the copied raw string from Font Awesomes github page.
You need to change two small things within the svg string:
1: Add a fill="black" attribute to the path/s elements - this allows the color to be change by Wordpress.
2: (optional) Change the width and height to 20, as this is the admin width/height size and seems to result it a crisper result.